# Mongodb production server too slow compared to staging

Tags: vps, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

We have two sets of db and app servers running on Rackspace VPS.
Production and Staging. The app is on Rails and db is MongoDB.

While staging(with as many documents as prod, 55k) works just fine,
production server is terribly slow. By a factor of 20 or more.
Even simple queries take close to 18 secs!

Here's what I did so far and I still can't get to the bottom of it.

- Restarted Mongo service.
- Checked ping times b/w app and db servers to see if network was the issue. It isn't.
- Explicitly ran create_indexes on the models but to no avail.
- Enabled mongo profiling option but it gave me no extra info than what I already had.

Here's the mongostat snapshot of production when some db calls are running:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults locked % idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  1.95g  4.55g   122m     76        0          0       0|0     1|0    62b     1k     2   09:07:25 
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  1.95g  4.55g   119m    121        0          0       0|0     1|0    62b     1k     2   09:07:26 
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  1.95g  4.55g   120m     80        0          0       0|0     1|0    62b     1k     2   09:07:27 
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  1.95g  4.55g   118m    116        0          0       0|0     1|0    62b     1k     2   09:07:28
```

Why are there so many faults? Is it normal?
Any help/insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Turns out this had nothing to do with Mongo at all. The culprit was 'whoospie', the ubuntu error reporting package that was depriving mongo of RAM because of a memory leak https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/998521. apt-get removed it.

Comment: you can add this as an answer (and perhaps add a bit of detail about how you identified the culprit) and accept the answer yourself once enough time has gone by - I'll upvote it - knowing that whoopsie can go nuts is important :)

Comment: sure. i'll do that

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the culprit was something else all together. Ubuntu's error reporting package called Whoopsie.
Here's how it was tracked.

- Mongostat showed unusually high number of faults which meant the data wasn't available in RAM and was mongo was probably hitting the disk for every query.
- Then I issued the Linux **free** command. It didn't help. It actually misleads when reporting free RAM. Look here www.linuxatemyram. com
- **top** command did no good either and it always showed that the highest memory usage was by mongo which went no higher that 20%. Why wasn't mongo using the remaining memory then?!
- A quick google search for system/memory monitoring tools showed **htop** as a favorite.

Here's the **htop** output on the server.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CLnI.png -- image

A whopping 43.7% RAM eaten by whoopsie!! Quite an oops moment.
Turns out it affected both production and staging servers but staging still survived to an extent. A few more google searches later I discovered that this indeed was a bug on Ubuntu.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/998521

I did not think that whoopsie - Ubuntu crash database submission daemon- was needed on my server as a critical component.
Went ahead and *apt-get removed* the *purged* the packages from all servers.